# SQL Server : SSIS Passing Variable between package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS job that contains 4 packages to perform ETL job

in the first package we use "select newid()" function to create an unique ID for that ETL process

wondering how can I pass that variable value to all ETL package so all 4 package can use the same ID

Execute package task is out of the picture cause we want the job to have 4 steps (perform by 4 packages)

Can anyone point me a direction ?

Thanks

Comment: Just make a parent package that sets the ID then pass that as a variable to the other packages using an Execute Package Task.

Comment: Work around would be to write the value to a file in the first package and read it in with the other three.  Or write the value to a table.  Cheesy but it would work.

Comment: @user3083310 why write to a file? If you're writing anywhere why not a database? You could build a whole control stucture.

Comment: Zane, that is one way we think of, however it is not practical just to create one package for generating ID. Thanks Anyway!

Comment: Zane, I agree that writing to a file isn't the best way.  Just coming up with options which is why I said table as well.

Comment: SSIS generates a unique ID for you for each package - the system variable ExecutionInstanceGUID. On the run of the first package, you could then write that into a database or a file for use by the next packages.

Comment: Yeah so far writing the variable into database and ask the following package to retrieve the value from database seems to be the solution. 
If anyone can comes up with batter solution or any idea I will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a "Master Control Package" to generate the ID, store it in a variable, then use Execute Package Tasks to call the sub-packages.

This makes your SQL Agent job definition simpler (1 step calling the MCP), and you can leverage out-of-the-box features of SSIS like parallel execution, conditional execution and restart control via checkpoints.